# c++ thread creation big overhead

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have the following code, which confuses me a lot:

```
float OverlapRate(cv::Mat& model, cv::Mat& img) {
    if ((model.rows!=img.rows)||(model.cols!=img.cols)) {
        return 0;
    }

    cv::Mat bgr[3];
    cv::split(img, bgr);

    int counter = 0;
    float b_average = 0, g_average = 0, r_average = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < model.rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < model.cols; j++) {
            if((model.at<uchar>(i,j)==255)){
                counter++;
                b_average += bgr[0].at<uchar>(i, j);
                g_average += bgr[1].at<uchar>(i, j);
                r_average += bgr[2].at<uchar>(i, j);
            }
        }
    }

    b_average = b_average / counter;
    g_average = g_average / counter;
    r_average = r_average / counter;

    counter = 0;
    float b_stde = 0, g_stde = 0, r_stde = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < model.rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < model.cols; j++) {
            if((model.at<uchar>(i,j)==255)){
                counter++;
                b_stde += std::pow((bgr[0].at<uchar>(i, j) - b_average), 2); 
                g_stde += std::pow((bgr[1].at<uchar>(i, j) - g_average), 2); 
                r_stde += std::pow((bgr[2].at<uchar>(i, j) - r_average), 2);                 
            }
        }
    }

    b_stde = std::sqrt(b_stde / counter);
    g_stde = std::sqrt(g_stde / counter);
    r_stde = std::sqrt(r_stde / counter);

    return (b_stde + g_stde + r_stde) / 3;
}


void work(cv::Mat& model, cv::Mat& img, int index, std::map<int, float>& results){
    results[index] = OverlapRate(model, img);
}

int OCR(cv::Mat& a, std::map<int,cv::Mat>& b, const std::vector<int>& possible_values)
{
        int recog_value = -1;
        clock_t start = clock(); 

        std::thread threads[10];
        std::map<int, float> results;
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            threads[i] = std::thread(work, std::ref(b[i]), std::ref(a), i, std::ref(results));
        }

        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
            threads[i].join();


        float min_score = 1000;
        int min_index = -1;
        for(auto& it:results)
        {
            if (it.second < min_score) {
                min_score = it.second;
                min_index = it.first;
            }
        }

        clock_t end = clock();
        clock_t t = end - start;
        printf ("It took me %d clicks (%f seconds) .\n",t,((float)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

        recog_value = min_index;
}
```

What the above code does is just simple optical character recognition. I have one optical character as an input and compare it with  0 - 9 ten standard character models to get the most similar one, and then output the recognized value.

When I execute the above code without using ten threads running at the same time, the time is 7ms. BUT, when I use ten threads, it drops down to 1 or 2 seconds for a single optical character recognition.

What is the reason?? The debug information tells that thread creation consumes a lot of time, which is this code:

```
threads[i] = std::thread(work, std::ref(b[i]), std::ref(a), i, std::ref(results));
```

Why? Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking "why does it take long to create a thread?" ?

Comment: Is `work` allowed to change `model` or `img`? How thread-safe do you feel `results` is, since you modify it in every thread?

Comment: Try timing only the thread creation separately, and the loop calling join separately, and of course keep the timing for the full function. Then you should be able to narrow down what part of the code is taking time.

Comment: @kfsone work does not change these two mat structures. I use index parameter to allow different thread to write results vector. I think it is thread safe

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I tried it. And it shows that the thread creation takes a lot of time

Comment: @ZivS I am not sure why in the code above, the thread creation is time consuming?

Comment: @Johnnylin It is not thread-safe. Had you used `std::vector` with preset size it would be fine, but `std::map` is (itself, not only its elements) modified by a call to `operator[]`, resulting in a data race.

Comment: @Eichhörnchen what you mean is I change std::map<int, float> to std:: vector. But inside the function, std::vector is still accessed by operator []. Can you give me more explanation? Thanks.

Comment: If thread creation is getting you down, [consider a thread pool](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/173575/what-is-a-thread-pool) with one thread per processing core you have available. Each thread is created once and has a queue of jobs to perform. A thread per job may sound nice, but more threads than cores means you have threads getting in each other's way and slowing the job down.

Comment: So you have code that takes 7ms and thought "that's way too long, my users will all get bored I really have to speed it up"? There's no point trying to speed something up that takes no time to begin with.

Comment: @Johnnylin Yes exactly that, change `std::map<int,float>` to `std::vector<float>` and construct `results` with the correct size: `std::vector<float> results(10);`. I can't see any reason you used `std::map` in the first place. If all indices from 0 to 10 are required to be present then a vector is much simpler and more efficient. Or you can pass a reference/pointer to the single `float` element to `work`, instead of the whole container reference and an index, i.e. take a `float&` and pass `std::ref(results[i])` to `std::thread`. Then the container type wouldn't matter.

Comment: @Johnnylin You might consider splitting your code up so that you don't duplicate work in the threads: http://pastebin.com/7whnjBbk

Comment: @kfsone Thanks for the suggestion. I will update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running multiple threads is useful in only 2 contexts: you have multiple hardware cores (so the threads can run simultaneously) OR each thread is waiting for IO (so one thread can run while another thread is waiting for IO, like a disk load or network transfer).

Your code is not IO bound, so I hope you have 10 cores to run your code. If you don't have 10 cores, then each thread will be competing for scarce resources, and the scarcest resource of all is L1 cache space. If all 10 threads are fighting for 1 or 2 cores and their cache space, then the caches will be "thrashing" and give you 10-100x slower performance.

Try running benchmarking your code 10 different times, with N=1 to 10 threads and see how it performs.

(There is one more reason the have multiple threads, which is when the cores support hyper threading. The OS will"pretend" that 1 core has 2 virtual processors, but with this you don't get 2x performance. You get something between 1x and 2x. But in order to get this partial boost, you have to run 2 threads per core)

Comment: Yes, I think this is the reason. Would it be better if i use a thread pool ?

Comment: @Johnnylin a thread pool will make no difference, it is just a collection of thread in a single object. what you may want to change is providing Mat by value (to increase local thread cache) and spawning no more than the number of threads in your system

Comment: @UmNyobe While worth investigating, I'm pretty sure that "cv::Mat" is some form of image, and if the image size is particularly large you might actually blow the cache away passing by value.

Answer (score 0):

Not always is efficient to use threads. If you use threads on small problem, then managing threads cost more time and resources then solving the problem. You must have enough work for threads and good managing work over threads.

If you want to know how many threads you can use on problem or how big must be problem, find Isoeffective functions (psi1, psi2, psi3) from theory of parallel computers.